# How do I select different proportion of sample from different group in tibble

Tags: r, tidyverse

How do I select different proportion of sample from different group in tibble.

Below a sample tibble is created. It has 100 0s and 800 1s. I want to randomly select 80% of 0s and 20% of 1s.

sample_frac or sample_n doesn't allow different sampling for each group [link to their documentation](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/sample.html)

```
library(tidyverse)

a <- c(rep(0, 100),
       rep(1, 1000))

tbl <- tibble(a)

# select 80% of 0s and 20% of 1s

b <- tbl %>%
  group_by(a) %>%
  sample_frac(size = 0.2)
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're looking for stratified sampling. `dplyr` provides the newer `slice_sample` (or `sample_n`/`sample_frac` in older versions). Just provide the weights for each level in a vector like the below, then feed it into the `weight_by` parameter.

```
# provide proportions 
weights <- ifelse(a == 0, 0.8, 0.2)
# feeds weights into sample function
b <- tbl %>%
    slice_sample(prop = 0.2, weight_by = weights)
```